# Solving a nonlinear second order ODE initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following problem.
\begin{cases}
    y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y+(1-y^2)y=0 & \text{for }x>0,\\
    y(0)=0,
\end{cases}
where $y=y(x)\in\mathbb R$.

1. Use the method of Frobenius to solve it.
2. Prove that there exists a solution $y$ which satisfies $y(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)=1$.
3. Prove that there exists a solution $y$ which satisfies that $y$ has infinitely many zeros.

We are told to solve this problem; however, get stuck even at the first step. We have never encounter this system, and failed to use the method of Frobenius to solve it.

Comment: From which book this problem from? section/page number?  This is a research problem, not typical problem given in standard textbook as HW problem. Because it is non-linear. Neither Maple nor Mathematica can solve it using series or Asymptotic.  See [power-series-solutions-for-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equations-reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40403/power-series-solutions-for-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equations-reference)   some non-linear ode's can be solved using series methods, but many can't.

Comment: @Nasser This is a HW problem assigned by professor in undergraduate ODE course.

Comment: Could you share the textbook name/page number? Or was it not from a textbook? but as I said, neither Maple nor Mathematica can solve it. This tells me it is not likely to have analytical solution.

Comment: This is not a textbook problem I think...

Comment: This looks similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164614/numerical-solution-to-2nd-order-nonlinear-ode/3164652#3164652. The ideas there were used to get better boundary conditions for a numerical solution over a finite interval starting above the singular point $x=0$, they show the structure of a possible solution but are not a proof of for the claims here.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I'm thinking about whether this assay could help.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326190500_On_the_coupling_of_the_homotopy_perturbation_and_Frobenius_method_for_exact_solutions_of_singular_nonlinear_differential_equations

Comment: Not really.You get a better approximation of the initial segment that way, allowing for longer step sizes there. But the real challenge is the behavior at infinity, to hit the saddle point. That requires a time-dependent perturbation of the stable manifold of the limit case. As is the case of any saddle point, the slightest deviation from the true path will lead to a hyperbolic curve that leads exponentially away from the desired solution.